# Uniform parametrisation of $SO(3)$

Tags: metric-spaces, topological-groups

Does there exist a map from a hypercube of some dimension to $SO(3)$ such that pushforward measure of standard measure on the hypercube is invariant under action of $SO(3)$ on itself?

Comment: Euler angles? ${}$

Comment: Euler angles are not even uniform on a sphere (equator is lighter than poles)

Comment: Perhaps use the rotation vector (2 coordinates) and the rotation angle (one coordinate)?

Comment: @JCAA Ok, having another look in wikipedia for euler angles $dV = sin x dx dy dz$. So we just need to fix first coordinate by appropriate transform.

Comment: Any two smooth measures on a cube of equal volume are diffeomorphic via a measure preserving diffeomorphism.

Comment: It's probably trivially true if you don't assume continuity (there's a measure-preserving isomorphism from $[0,1]$ to any reasonable atom-free probability space).

Comment: It is bizzare that noone wrote up an explicit 'skewed euler angles' solution. I'd be happy to mark that as resolved if it happens.

Answer (score 0):

There is a very general theorem that takes care of this (but maybe too general for your purposes), it is a generalization of Moser's Theorem:

> Suppose that $M$ is an $m$-dimensional compact manifold with corners (say, a cube), equipped with two volume forms $\omega_1, \omega_2$ of equal volume. Then there is a diffeomorphism $f: M\to M$ such that $f^*(\omega_2)=\omega_1$.

See

*Bruveris, Martins; Michor, Peter W.; Parusiński, Adam; Rainer, Armin*, [**Moser’s theorem on manifolds with corners**](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/proc/14130), Proc. Am. Math. Soc. 146, No. 11, 4889-4897 (2018). [ZBL1398.58004](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:1398.58004).

Now, in your situation, take $G=SO(3)$; normalize its volume form to have unit volume.  Using for instance Euler angles obtain a parameterization of $G$ by the 3-dimensional unit cube $I^3$. Pull-back the volume form from $G$ to a form $\omega_2$ on $I^3$.   Let $\omega_1$ be the standard volume form on $I^3$. Then, generalized Moser's theorem will imply existence of a diffeomorphism $f: I^3\to I^3$ such that $f^*(\omega_2)=\omega_1$, i.e. $f_*(\omega_1)=\omega_2$. Now, compose with the above parameterization $I^3\to G$.

Comment: Pull-back measures require some care, but this seems like a powerful and worthwhile theorem.